# Monitor files in directory in C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that will scan a file or directory and determine whether the file has been added, changed, or deleted. I have been given the following structure to use, but I am seriously drawing a blank on how to use the integer values to detect changes. I did some research online and found that the stat struct has a member `st_mtime`; that returns the time of last modification. How can I store the previous time to compare the new time against it? I should mention that I have limited experience in this and this will be my first time using the `stat()` function.

```
struct statinfo 
{
    char fileName[MAX_FILENAME]; //file name
    int lastCycle, thisCycle; //to detect changes
    struct stat status; //information from stat()
};
```

I am not allowed to use `inotify` — I was told to use `stat()` and `getdents()`.

Comment: _How can I store the previous time to compare the new time against it?_ Are you really asking how to store a copy of a value?

Comment: Yes. I need to be able to compare the time last modified in the current scan to the last scan.

Comment: Look at the inode number, device number, size and the 3 or 4 time stamps associated with a file name (in the `struct stat` information); if any of those changed, the file/directory did.  Names missing have to be tracked carefully.  Names added are easier.  You'll end up copying the current `stat` stucture determined using the name returned by `readdir()`/`getdents()` into your structure; you'll be able to compare what you got before with what you got this time.

Comment: So you stored the stat object from your last scan in your statinfo. Then, after some period of time, you call stat again and populate a new stat object. Finally, you compare the st_mtime members. I'm not sure which of these steps is causing you difficulty.

Comment: probably the fact that I'm dense. Thank you Useless, I think that will work fine. >_<

Comment: No problem, and everyone's got stuck on something that seems simple afterwards. I just wasn't sure which bit was the question.